# WARNING: you seem to not be using the Xerial SQLite driver

Tags: sqlite, ormlite

I used libs

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.48</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.48</version>
    </dependency>
```

Run a main class shows too many errors:

WARNING: you seem to not be using the Xerial SQLite driver

How to disable it

help me

Answer (score 4):

You can use an older version of **sqlite-jdbc** to avoid this incompatibility:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
   <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>3.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or just add the dependency which got removed in 3.8 versions, therefore causing error:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.10.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial.thirdparty</groupId>
    <artifactId>nestedvm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

OrmLite [checks](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/blob/d13c3e830617bd8ccbaee78166d6baadf6159087/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/db/SqliteDatabaseType.java#L16) for existence of `org.ibex.nestedvm.Interpreter` class, which is not present in newer versions of Xerial driver. But you can simply create that class in your project, just empty class with no members to suppress the warning.

UPD: Check was [removed](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/commit/6da06aed7b4204791dd3964c04bc9343bbc21ca8) though not released yet.